# How to set up Django website with jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I don't know why, but I couldn't figure out how to activate jQuery on my website. All sites doing tutorials 'Starting jQuery on Django' started with JQuery already working on their site. Anyway, instead of downloading it and putting it in my folder somewhere, I decided to go the cheat-way and use Google's. 
Therefore, in my base page, I had the following piece of code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

And everything worked great, until I had to add some libraries. How do I set up my own jQuery so that it works with my templates?

Comment: Which libraries? Why do you use old version of jQuery?

Comment: @Daniil I was trying to install the sorttable.js library. And I was using an old version of jQuery because I was confused, trying many things, checking other websites' scripts, and just picked the first thing I saw that was different from what I had.

Comment: Those who are going to come here after me make sure to run: python manage.py collectstatic before you try to push changes to production. That's what solved my problem.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In the end, it turned out to be very easy. This is all one has to do:

First, make a folder named `static` inside your folder app:

```
mySite
---mytemplates
---mySite
---myApp
------static
```

Then download jQuery from their site [here](http://jquery.com/). You click 'Download' and it will take you to a different page with all the code. Left click on the code and select 'save as...'. Save it in the `static` folder.

Inside your `settings.py` file make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is under `INSTALLED_APPS` (it is there by default).

Lastly, inside your base page have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/jquery-1.8.0.js">
</script> 
//Make sure that the jQuery name is correct. With updates and different versions, 
//the number after 'jquery' will change
```

And now you can use jQuery throughout your site! (as long as the pages extend your basepage. If they don't, they will need the above piece of code in their html.)

This works for me while working on my local machine. I haven't tried actually deploying my site yet, so I hope this will still work.

Comment: Yes it will work. When you deploy though, file serving is not automatic.. you'll have to run `manage.py collectstatic` which will put static files into your `STATIC_ROOT` which then needs to be served by your server at the `STATIC_URL` URL.

Comment: I believe the convention has changed since this question was asked so here's the latest documentation on static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 15):

You can also just `pip install django-jquery`, and put `jquery` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Of course, you need to run `collectstatic` as always after. :)

That way you can just have it in your `requirements.txt` file if you use one.

Comment: last release of django-jquery was in 2016

Answer (score 5):

You may also use the python package `django-static-jquery`. For the moment, it comes with the more recent jquery libraries.

`pip install django-static-jquery=='version'`. Package & installation info here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-static-jquery/

Looks like the other package `django-jquery` not been updated in a while.

Comment: Both of these packages have final updates in 2015 and 2016 respectively. The best option today will be refer top answer. Or use another framework du jour, like Alpine or Hyperscript

Answer (score 1):

I put my jQuery file in the same place as SaiyanGirl.

In my `setting.py` I had this by default:

```
INSTALLED_APPS: = [
    ...
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

At the top of my HTML page I have this:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I have this in my head tag:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-3.5.0.js' %}"></script>
```

This is how I tested it (in the head tag too):

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload = function() {
       if (window.jQuery) {
          alert('jQuery is loaded');
       } else {
          alert('jQuery is not loaded');
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have two "}" missing in the last row...